# Angular, share directive template between click functions

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive which, when called, passes in a `controller` and an `array`.

In the controller I pass in, there is an object I want to loop over.

my html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="protocolCtrl as pctrl">

            <button type="button" id="protocol" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="pctrl.getUpdatedList()"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Modify Current Protocols</button>


            <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->

            <modal-directive list="pctrl" headers="['ID', 'Protocol']"></modal-directive>

        </div>

    </div>


    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div class="jumbotron" ng-controller="categoryCtrl as cctrl">   
            <button type="button" id="category" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="cctrl.getUpdatedList()"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Modify Current Categories</button>


            <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->

            <modal-directive list="cctrl" headers="['ID', 'Category']"></modal-directive>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

My problem is that no matter what I do, it's always the **FIRST** directive in the html that showes up, no matter what button I press.

My `directive` looks like this:

```
.directive('modalDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: '/directives/modal-directive.html',
        scope: {
            list: '=',
            headers: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){

            console.log(attrs.list + ' | ' + attrs.headers);
        }
    };
});
```

My `modal-directive.html` looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>

      <tr>
        <th ng-repeat="h in headers"> {{ h }} </th>
      </tr>

    </thead>

    <tbody>

       <!-- Loop through -->

      <tr ng-repeat="l in list.list">

            <!--Access the actual values inside each of the objects in the array-->

            <td ng-repeat="data in l"> {{ data }} </td>

            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                     data-toggle="modal">Edit</button>
            </td>

            <td>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="list.removeData(l)"
                        data-dismiss="modal">Remove</button>
            </td>

      </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

Am I using isolated scopes wrong, or is it something else I need to change in order to make this work?

**Update**

Here is a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10133/), that demonstrates the problem.

No matter which button i click, it displays the same text in the modal body.

Comment: what do you mean "passes in a `controller`" ? pctrl is a funcion then ?

Comment: @kyori I pass in the the controller itself basically. And that means I can also access an object that is defined in the controller.

Comment: Then i think you should link it with "&" instead of "="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need two controllers and two directives to achieve this. Below is an example of how you can do this. Notice I moved the controller to the row instead of having separate controllers for each column. The controller `myCtrl` now handles the click functions which are bound to the buttons using the `ng-click` attribute. This then determines the which text should be placed where by calling there respective functions. IE `proto()` and `cat()`

*Now this may not be ideal for your situation depending on how you plan on the architecture of your application. But it works for your current problem in terms of what you have provided.*

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="TM">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="myCtrl as modalControl">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="jumbotron" >
                <button 
                    ng-click='proto()'
                    type="button" id="protocol" 
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
                    data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#modal">Modify Current Protocols
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="jumbotron">   
                <button
                    ng-click='cat()'
                    type="button" 
                    id="category" 
                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
                    data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#modal">Modify Current Categories
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--IN THIS MODAL YOU CAN ADD/CHANGE/DELETE DATA-->
        <modal-directive ctrl="modalControl"></modal-directive>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Angular JS**

```
angular.module('TM', [])

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.text ='default';

    $scope.proto = function() {
        this.text = 'Now looking at the protocol part'
    }
    $scope.cat = function() {
        this.text = 'Now looking at the category part'
    }
})
.directive('modalDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: true,       
        template:  ['<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">', 
                      '<div class="modal-dialog">',
                        '<div class="modal-content">',
                        '<div class="modal-header">',
                        '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="modal-body">',
                        '<p> {{ text }} </p>',
                        '</div>',
                        '<div class="modal-footer">',
                        '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>',
                        '</div>',
                        '</div>', 
                        '</div>',
                        '</div>'].join('')
    }
});
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10193/

### **UPDATE:**

Okay, I took another look. And even though the above example works. I noticed that I have a few extra things that I didn't necessarily need. For example `myCtrl as modalControl` doesn't need the `as modalControl` part. Below is an updated example. I did this one with some different simplified markup.

**HTML:**

```
<body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <button ng-click="one()">One</button>
        <button ng-click="two()">Two</button>
        <test-directive></test-directive>
    </div>    
</body>
```

**Angular Example (without Isolated Scope)**

```
angular.module('TestApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){

    $scope.text ='default';

    $scope.one = function() {
        this.text = 'this is one'
    }
    $scope.two = function() {
        this.text = 'this is two'
    }
})
.directive('testDirective', function(){
    return {
        template: "<div id='test'>{{text}}</div>"  
    }
});
```

**Demo 2:**

https://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/v8tczaea/12/

Note this..

```
restrict: 'E',
scope: true
```

Was also not needed because I am not using Isolated scope in this example. More info here https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thank you very much. There is no need for isolate scope variables?

Comment: Yes I believe that is correct, in your case you wouldn't want to isolate it because you are trying to change the content but not the template. So in this case the scope of the template changes, but the template remains the same.

Comment: ok :) The reason I asked was when I changed your fiddle a little bit (from $scope to the use of `this` and `controller as` syntax. I needed to add a variable in scope. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10196/

Comment: I had a couple things I didn't need in the original answer. So I have updated the answer.. Even though the first worked.. I think the updated is more accurate and I hope it explains things a bit better.

Comment: thanks :) But I'd rather stick to the `controller as` syntax. Excellent explanation here: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: Interesting.. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10142/).

The reason is that `data-target` value points to the DOM element id of the modal. If you fixed this id in the directive template, clicking on the button will always initiate the modal with id `modal`. So you need to make the `modalId` as another parameter of the directive.

---

By the way, you can pass a controller to a directive. Just like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9L07epkv/2/):

```
angular.module('Joy', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    this.value = 'Joy';
}])
    .directive('passMeContrller', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ctrl: '=',
        },
        template: '<div>Value: {{ctrl.value}}</div>'
    };
}]);
```

The HTML:

```
<div ng-app="Joy" ng-controller="MyCtrl as c">
    <div pass-me-contrller ctrl="c"></div>
    <hr>
    <div ng-bind="c.value"></div>
</div>
```

Because the controller itself is just a JavaScript object.

Just a reminder: you are using `protocolCtrl as pctrl`, so you need to specify like `this.list=...`.

[If you want to pass in a function to the isolated scope, use `&`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller).

---

**However**, I suggest not to pass in the whole `controller` to a directive. A [controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) is designed to:

- Set up the initial state of the $scope object.
- Add behavior to the $scope object.

Controllers are not supposed to be reused. Usually there are many properties on the `$scope`, while some of them passed to the directive will not be used by it.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how this helps me solve my problem. What would I need to change in my code?

Comment: Put your code alive on JSFiddle or Plunker. Need to show your controller as well.

Comment: I'll try and re-create the problem in a fiddle and get back to you :)

Comment: question is now updated with a fiddle, that hopefully makes the problem more clear.