# AngularJS: JS Fiddle Failed to load Resource

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs-directive, jsfiddle

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10129/)

Here is my angular code:

```
angular.module('TM', [])

.controller('protocolCtrl', function(){
    this.categoryText = 'Now looking at the protocol part'
})

.controller('categoryCtrl', function(){
    this.protocolText = 'Now looking at the category part'
})

.directive('modalDirective', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            list: '='
        },
        template: ['<div id="modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">',
                      '<div class="modal-dialog">',
                        '</div>',
                        '</div>'].join('')
    }
});
```

If I use the template html directly in the HTML file, it shows, but not otherwise.

The mistake is hopefully really minor, but any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at just using the UI-bootstrap modal?  https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/  it'll do this all for you.

Comment: Your angular JS is not loading in your fiddle. 404

Comment: Works fine.. Just need to fix your fiddle. Use this link instead..  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js  Here is a demo .. https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10131/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems fine. But your angular link in your fiddle is broken. When making an Angular JS fiddle you should copy the CDN URL from the Angularjs.org website and add it as your External Resource for JS fiddle.

[image]

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js
```

**Demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/10131/

Comment: If you have time - I'd really appreciated if you can take a look at this as well : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31516980/passing-in-parameters-when-calling-a-directive-in-angularjs/31520413#31520413

Comment: @Nilzone-, Did you start a fiddle for that question?

Comment: I'm working on reproducing the error in a fiddle right now, and then I'll update the question

Comment: I updated the question I linked you, with the fiddle now, if you'd like to have a look.

Comment: Okay I will take a look